# Cursor position change in TMemo

Tags: delphi

I have a component derived from TMemo. Do you know what Windows message I should intercept to react on text cursor position changes? I mean text cursor, which change position by pressing arrow keys or by left mouse button click. I am on Delphi 7. OnMouseDown or OrKeyPress events work for arrow keys but not for LMB.

Comment: One wonders what you will do in response to caret pos change

Comment: Memo is part of flowchart graphical component. Code generated from this flowchart is displayed on separate form in TSynMemo. When I move cursor from one line to another (so in vertical direction) in memo on flowchart I want to move active line in editor to correct line. All I need is to react on changing by mouse. I don't know why but mouse clicks do not work in OnKeyPress event. Other mouse events (e.g. OnMouseDown) either are not triggered.

Comment: The problem with handling any events to detect if the cursor moves, is that the cursor usually moves in response to that event, and not always before the handler is called. I frequently found I was getting the position of where it was, not where it was moving to. To resolve this, I post and consume a user message, and handle the caret change on receiving the message; by then it's moved and I can detect it's new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted it out. Not working mouse events was my mistake. To respond to caret position changes in TMemo you can make combination of two events: OnKeyUp (for arrow keys) and OnMouseDown:

```
procedure TSomeMemo.OnKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    if Key in [VK_UP, VK_DOWN, VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT] then
        OnMouseDown(Sender, mbLeft, Shift, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TSomeMemo.OnMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
    row,col: integer;
begin
    if Button = mbLeft then
    begin 
        row := SendMessage(Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, SelStart, 0);
        col := SelStart - SendMessage(Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, row, 0);
        ... 
    end;
end;
```

Comment: There are other ways for the caret to move, and mouse down is the wrong event to handle anyway. Please also try to answer the question that was asked. *Do you know what Windows message I should intercept to react on text cursor position changes?*

Answer (score 3):

You can store `CaretPos` property value and compare it in `OnKeyPress` and `OnClick` events. Calling some procedure if it has changed.

Comment: There are other causes for the caret position to change.

Comment: Yes, @David-Heffernan, but in these causes the procedure can be manually called (for instance after the code inserts a line into `TMemo`). We do not know how heavy is the text processing procedure of user3848246. So it might take too much processor time if run in `OnIdle`, at least because it will be called more frequently.

Comment: I don't see why it called more frequently in `OnIdle`. Clearly you only do the processing if the position has changed. I'm not sure how you are managing to make performance related decisions based on the information in the question. I was just trying to be helpful by pointing out that there are more ways for caret position to change.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @David-Heffernan. We just offer the author of the question to decide which of the solutions is more useful for his application and suits him in his current work. And you are right that there can be other reasons for change of CaretPos.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know what Windows message I should intercept to react on text cursor position changes?

There is no notification event for change in caret position in a Win32 edit control.

You could perhaps detect such a change by polling, in response to the application's `OnIdle` event.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only speciality you want, there are already some answers. If you want to extend on TMemo's functionality more than that you will sooner or later find, that you're better off to use something like SynEdit, which incidentally also supports reacting to cursor position changes.

Comment: I happen to use Synedit in this program but not for this memo actually. Could you elaborate a bit more? After having quick look in Synedit code I did not find anything useful. Just to clarify it is not about mouse cursor but text cursor.

Comment: Hm, my memory tricked me again. No, there is no event in SynEdit, when the cursor position changes. There is the OnCommandProcessed event which I used instead.